# Overcome Flash Player SoundChannel or Sound limit

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

From the Flash player specification, it supported up to 15/16 or 32 sounds in a buffer, which mean any more sounds is load beyond that limit will either caused buffer stop working.

Is there any class to override to increase sounds to 1024 or greater?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it can not be changed in any way.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: You could mix them yourself with some extra programming.

Investigate the ["sampleData" event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#event%3asampleData) for flash.media.Sound.

It might add some lag, so depending on the application it will be useful or not.